# What is a wrapper type in Graphql?

Tags: rest, api, graphql, wrapper, graphql-js

I am learning the official GraphQl doc.

When I come to the chapter **introspection**  [link here](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/)

I have encounter something called wrapper type.

**input**:

```
{
  __type(name: "Droid") {
    name
    fields {
      name
      type {
        name
        kind
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "__type": {
      "name": "Droid",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "type": {
            "name": null,    # here 
            "kind": "NON_NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "type": {
            "name": null,    # here 
            "kind": "NON_NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "friends",
          "type": {
            "name": null,    #  here 
            "kind": "LIST"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "friendsConnection",
          "type": {
            "name": null,       # here 
            "kind": "NON_NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "appearsIn",
          "type": {
            "name": null,      # here 
            "kind": "NON_NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "primaryFunction",
          "type": {
            "name": "String",     # normal here
            "kind": "SCALAR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The article claims the name of **those type of fields of type** is NULL because  it's a **" wrapper" type of kind NON_NULL**

Could someone explain what is exactly a **wrapper type**? Better provide an example or code to explain why **primaryFunction** has a name but others do not.

Answer (score 3):

From the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Wrapping-Types):

> All of the types so far are assumed to be both nullable and singular: e.g. a scalar string returns either null or a singular string.
>
> A GraphQL schema may describe that a field represents list of another types; the List type is provided for this reason, and wraps another type.
>
> Similarly, the Non-Null type wraps another type, and denotes that the resulting value will never be null (and that an error cannot result in a null value).
>
> These two types are referred to as “wrapping types”; non‐wrapping types are referred to as “named types”. A wrapping type has an underlying named type, found by continually unwrapping the type until a named type is found.

A wrapping type wraps another type, which itself may also be a wrapping type. However, as you "unwrap" each wrapping type, eventually you have to hit a named type that all those wrapping types are associated with. In other words, wrapping types can never be used by themselves. A wrapping type always has exactly one named type it's associated to.

In introspection, to determine what type the wrapping type is wrapping, use the `ofType` field:

```
{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
      ofType {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can add additional levels to potentially "unwrap" types further:

```
{
  __schema {
    types {
      name
      ofType {
        name
        ofType {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As to *why* introspection doesn't show a name for these types, it's because the spec specifically prohibits it. Take a look at the section for the [List](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Type-Kinds.List) type:

> Lists represent sequences of values in GraphQL. A List type is a type modifier: it wraps another type instance in the ofType field, which defines the type of each item in the list.
>
> Fields
>
> - kind must return __TypeKind.LIST.
> - ofType: Any type.
> - All other fields must return null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some snippet from a tutorial I have done the other day. It represents a type wrapped with GraphQLNonNull operator (it's for the server side):

```
const ContestStatusType = require('./contest-status')
const NameType = require('./name')

module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'ContestType',
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    description: { type: GraphQLString },
    status: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(ContestStatusType) },
    createdAt: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    createdBy: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    names: {
      type: new GraphQLList(NameType),
      resolve(obj, args, { loaders, pgPool }) {
        return loaders.namesForContestIds.load(obj.id);
        return pgdb(pgPool).getNames(obj)
      }
    }
  }
});
```